# QGIS Graphical Modeler: How to execute unrelated process chain after first one is finished?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Imagine you have a process chain which ends in uploading a result to a connected PostGIS database. When this is finished, I would like to make a modification in a different table in the database to log the time when the previous process chain was last executed.

How can I generally combine unrelated processes in one model? Since there is no algorithm output which I can link to start the new process, I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the the process that has to finish as a dependancy to the process that needs to begin afterwards.

[image: Algorithm Dependancy]

This will keep the SQL from running until the the other tasks are finished.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful!